# Creating a z-test over rows using dplyr mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, dplyr

I have a dataframe called clusters with various counts and totals and want to perform a simple two-prop z-test over rows to create a new column called pvals. When I use this code, pvals ends up being zero. When I replace the z-test with a simple `sum()` function, pvals becomes a summation for all values. This should be quite trivial, and I'm aware I could just alternatively iterate through, but I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

```
clusters<- read.csv(file="clusters.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

clusters <- clusters %>% mutate(
  pvals = prop.test(x=c(Charter.Count,Other.Count),n=c(Charter.Total,Other.Total), alternative="two.sided")$p.value
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this as I don't have your clusters dataset, but it sounds like you need to use `rowwise()`:

```
clusters<- read.csv(file="clusters.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

clusters <- clusters %>% 
rowwise() %>%
mutate(
  pvals = prop.test(x=c(Charter.Count,Other.Count),n=c(Charter.Total,Other.Total), alternative="two.sided")$p.value
)
```